# difference between < extends Comparable > and < extends Comparable < T > >?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I tried to cast String to T type, but it says "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to 'T'. 
However, when I remove "< T >" from < T extends Comparable< T > >, and fix that to < T extends Comparable >, it is okay. What is the difference?
Below is the code:

```
public class Graph<T extends Comparable<T>> {

public void createGraph(Scanner in) {
    String line;
    String[] elements;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        elements = line.split("\\s+");
        insertVertex((T)elements[0]); // << This is the part
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph is of type `T`. That means I can have a graph of `Person`s, for example.

Then, in `createGraph`, you try to insert a `String` vertex in the graph. But `String` cannot be cast to a `Person`.

If you want a `createGraph` method that creates a `Graph<String>`, then you need it to make it `static`, like this:

```
public Graph<String> createGraph(Scanner in) {
    String line;
    String[] elements;
    Graph<String> graph = new Graph<>();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        elements = line.split("\\s+");
        graph.insertVertex(elements[0]);
    }
    // ...
    // Anything else, like adding edges
    // ...
    return graph;
}
```

**EDIT**: The reason your code compiles with no problem when you remove the `<T>` in `Comparable<T>` is that it becomes a graph of Comparables (instead of a graph of persons or a graph of strings), and then there's no problem in adding both a String and a Person to it.